# How to include a RaisedButton in a Container

Tags: flutter, widget, containers, addition

I want a Raisedbutton that appears after the Container.

```
 @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Galeria clase 1'),
          ),
          body: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8), child: galeria(array)),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _optionsDialogBox,
            tooltip: 'Pick Image',
            child: Icon(Icons.add_outlined),
          ),
        );
      }enter code here
```

I tried this but there is the next error -> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#02bd4 relayoutBoundary=up1

```
  body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        (Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: galeria(
            array,
          ),
        )),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Guardar red"),
          onPressed: () {
            safeNeuralNetwork();
          },
        ),
      ]),
```

Comment: What does `galeria` do?

Comment: galeria Funciton

Answer (score 0):

galeria  Function

```
Widget galeria(List<Uint8List> array) {
    return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      itemCount: array.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.deepPurple,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[Image.memory(array[index])],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      // staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => new StaggeredTile.fit(1),
      staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => new StaggeredTile.fit(1),
      mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

StaggeredGridView (or nearly any ScrollView) widget can't work with unbounded (infinite) height like in your case. You can't have a Column widget and a ScrollView inside it without using Expanded or something like that. Why? Because you need something to limit the maximum height of that widget. In this case we will use an Expanded widget. So go and modify your code like this:

```
body: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        child: galeria(array),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      ),
    ),
    RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        safeNeuralNetwork();
      },
      child: Text("Guardar red"),
    ),
  ],
),
```

With this we basically said: ***"Hey, go and render this column but please, stick a RaisedButton at the bottom and use the remaining space for the StaggeredGridView."***.